# How to evaluated with hypergeometric functions?

Tags: integration, special-functions, hypergeometric-function, trigonometric-integrals

sHello to everyone, i would like a suggestion on how to evaluate these integrals using the hypergeometric functions:

$$\int_0^x \frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{1+a \ sinx+b \ cosx}} dx$$
where $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$.

Unfortunately, even after a lot of work, I did not get a compact formulation using the hypergeometric functions.

Thanks for your time and for your interest.

Tip: With some passage you get the following condition
$$\int_0^x \frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{1+a \ sinx+b \ cosx}} dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n} (\frac{1}{2})_n}{n!} ({a^{2}+b^{2}})^{\frac{n}{2}}\int_0^x [sin(x+\alpha)]^{n}  \ \ dsinx$$
Where $$\alpha=atan(\frac{b}{a})$$
Unfortunately, however, the latter does not seem easy to solve. It would be interesting to be able to solve it with the use of hypergeometric features.

Comment: have tried WolframAlpha?

Comment: $\int_0^x \, dx$ :(

Comment: You're right, in the past I was more accurate about these things, now I prefer to go to the basic concept :S

Comment: Wolfram returns a too unreasonable solution, I do not like it, I would like to find a more "simple" solution if so can be said

Comment: Looks like an elliptic integral to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy to express the integral in terms of Elliptic Integrals of first and second kind (below).

The Elliptic Integrals are related to some hypergeometric functions, but the relationships are complicated. See :
http://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegrals/EllipticF/26/01/
and http://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegrals/EllipticE2/26/01/

[image]

Comment: You're right, beautiful thought! I was too focused on my idea of resolution and I did not think about this possible choice. Thank you very much and good work.